# Getting Element ID by Name

Tags: c#, watin

So Basically right now I have some code and I am trying to manipulate it with WatIN in C#

```
 <li class=" p-pstctgry-li-ctgry">
    <a class="p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry " id="cat_18297" href="#"><span class="c-icon c-icon-category c-icon-category-18297"></span>Arts &amp; Crafts</a>
    </li>

 <li class=" p-pstctgry-li-ctgry">
    <a class="p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry " id="cat_20000" href="#"><span class="c-icon c-icon-category c-icon-category-20000"></span>Computers</a>
    </li>
```

What I want to do is capture all of the IDs and the label on the element. So example 18297, Arts & Crafts.

There is a few of these on the page so I want to pick them all up and get a way that I can easily reference to them. So say, Catagory is Computers then go to id='cat_20000'

Anyone have an idea on how I would go about completing this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily captured through jQuery. Any particular reason to grab them fro C# code?

Comment: trying to get data into a C# project for an work project and they want me to take this from a website.

Comment: I would say then... you need to play with regular expressions then. Capture the HTML (in decoded format) as string and try to grab the requisite parts using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and it can be optimized as well. In the foreach loop, you can get all links from the entire document or if you know that those links can be picked from a specific parent then you can pass `parent.Links`

```
        Dictionary<string, string> lnksValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (Link lnk in driver.Links)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lnk.Id))
            {
                if (lnk.Id.Contains('_'))
                {
                    lnksValues.Add(lnk.Id.Split('_')[1], lnk.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```